# Compiler complains about possible undefined in nested objects

Tags: typescript

I have the following sample code: [sample on typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20boolVar%3A%20number%20%7C%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(boolVar)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20boolVar.toString%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20objectVar%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20number%20%7C%20undefined%20%7D%20%3D%20%7Ba%3A%201%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20selector%20%3D%20%22a%22%3B%0D%0Aif%20(objectVar%5Bselector%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20objectVar%5Bselector%5D.toFixed%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A) (activate strictNullChecks)

```
 1. let boolVar: number | undefined;
 2. 
 3. if (boolVar) {
 4.     boolVar.toString; // all fine
 5. }
 6. 
 7. let objectVar: { [key: string]: number | undefined } = {a: 1};
 8. 
 9. const selector = "a";
10. if (objectVar[selector]) {
11.     objectVar[selector].toFixed; // Object is possible undefined? o0
12. }
```

Why does the compiler complains about line 11.: `Object is possible undefined` when I explicitly check for this object in line 10.?

Comment: Can TypeScript be multi-threaded?  If so, there's the possibility that `objectVar[selector]` could become undefined between the `if` check and the `if` block.  I found that if I saved `objectVar[selector]` to a variable before the `if` statement, and referenced that variable instead, the error went away.

Comment: @AlexPeters TypeScript transpiles to JavaScript and a crucial aspect of JS VMs is that they are single-threaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type guards (which is what you are using when you write `if (objectVar[selector])` and expect the type to change based on the check) do not work with index access. This is documented in [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11483) and [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530) issues. The reason for this is (as stated by @RyanCavanaugh in comments to the issue)

> Declined due to performance reasons. Since it should almost always be possible to write const j = list[i] instead, this shouldn't be too burdensome.

As is stated above the recommendation is to use a local variable :

```
let objectVar: { [key: string]: number | undefined } = {a: 1};

const selector = "a";
const objectVar_selector = objectVar[selector]; 
if (objectVar_selector) {
    objectVar_selector.toFixed; // Object is possible undefined? o0
}
```

Comment: Very nice. good walkaround. thanks for pointing that out for me :)